# Translucent menu bars and missing letters

Tags: unity, graphics, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on a new Toshiba Satellite.

Everything seems to be working OK, but I'm having some graphics related issues. Occasionally in Unity, the menu bars of my apps will turn translucent and will only become solid again if a drag and drop or maximize and minimize the application.

Even more troublesome is that occasionally there will be random missing letters in all of my applications (in the toolbars and menus), which doesn't seem to go away until I log out and then log in again.

I've tried changing the default font with Ubuntu Tweak Tool, but the result is the same. I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this issue. Any ideas? Thanks.

Example:

[Missing letters in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7HV6.png)

[Translucent toolbar in Kodi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfcN0.png)

Comment: I have the same problem on a 2015 X1 Carbon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--UPDATE--

Linux 4.0 and up have better support for newer hardware. 
You should simply update to Ubuntu 16.04 or install a 4.X kernel yourself.

---

This apparently deals with the Intel Graphics Drivers on some machines ; 
If you do not install [Intel's Graphics Driver](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) - then things like this happen.

Unfortunately, whoever is running that project made the poor decision to *remove all versions but the current* from the download list.

Thus, you cannot apply this fix unless you are running 14.10.

I, myself am in the same boat, and while I would like to update back to 14.10 or 15.04, my job requires 14.04.

SO, as of right now, here is what I have done:

1. Install compiz :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra
   ```
2. Scroll down to "Image Loading" - and check "Text"
3. Under "Utilities" - click "Workarounds" : 
   YMMV, here - and you may not want to do any of these: 
   Check:

   - QT Window Fix
   - Don't wait for vsync
   - Force full screen Redraws on repaint

I will edit this as I can verify which of the above options actually did the trick.

This seems to have fixed the font (after a couple of reboots...) 
But the transparent menu bar is still a problem...

Comment: If I wanted to download the Intel drivers (which I believe are baked into the Linux kernel?) I would download from intel not "01.org". Also, installing unsupported software is generally not the way to get it back to working. Since many of these report problems with Linux 4.4 that are fixed going back to 4.2 or up to 4.6 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1575000), installing the officially supported 4.2 or 4.6 Ubuntu linux kernel would be a better solution.

Comment: This answer was prior to kernel 4.X - and 01.org is where Intel will link you  if you click through their site. Updating the answer to reflect that.