# What happened to my Dash icons?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, unity-dash, icon-themes

The other day I noticed one of the icons in the left dash was missing. Today I noticed most of them are missing. What causes this, and could the miniSSD be going bad?

I have Icon-theme set to Human (the old icons) using Ubuntu Tweak Tool on 14.04 but this setting hasn't caused this issues for months now.

The home (on a hdd) is encrypted and maybe there is an error in reading it, as I see this in the system log:

```
compiz: pam_ecryptfs: seteuid error
```

[image: Empty Icons]

[image: Empty Icons]

Comment: I see it again today... but just one icon (Files) right now.

Comment: Message me when you are online.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is the intermittent graphical glitch in Linux 4.3-4.4 described [various](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594226/translucent-menu-bars-and-missing-letters/639633) [places](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1633207#p1633207), not just Ubuntu. You can install Ubuntu's older 4.2 version to fix it:

[Missing letters in menus and folder names](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582980/missing-letters-in-menus-and-folder-names/892298)

Answer (score 5):

You can check `/usr/share/icons` to see if all icons are present.

Further you run following commands:

[1] This will reset the Unity Launcher icons to their initial state:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

[2] Then you need to reset the Unity Settings in order to eliminate any unknown discrepancy. This will not affect any of your other CCSM settings.

```
unity --reset
```

Reboot the system and hopefully your problem will be solved.

Comment: well now *all* the icons are all showing... as they do >90% of the time... it would appear that shutting and opening laptop may fix (or un-fix) this?