# Where did my sytem font go and how can I get it back?

Tags: unity, suspend, fonts

I left my laptop suspended for a bit and when I re-opened it, most of my system fonts were hidden. On my desktop, a few folders have some random letters in their name visible, but most have disappeared:

[image: desktop]

And most of my title bars and dialog windows are totally opaque, as you can see in this screenshot of the screenshot dialog:

[image: screenshot dialog]

I'm not sure how to even begin to troubleshoot this. I'm sure I could restart my computer but there must be a better way to get my fonts back?

I read through [Translucent menu bars and missing letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594226/translucent-menu-bars-and-missing-letters) but this isn't something I've seen before and I've been on 16.04 LTS for quite some time, so I think this is a different issue.

Plus, I have compiz (the solution suggested in the answer to the above question) and it, too, is unusable at the moment:

[image: Compiz Screenshot]

Two months later, I'm still struggling with this. My fonts just kind of choke, usually after my computer has been asleep for a while. It's inconsistent which apps choke -- for instance right now there are zero letters on my desktop or my terminal but Firefox is fine. If I re-boot my computer everything is back just fine but that's obviously super inconvenient.

Logging out and back in would be a good option, but I'd have to memorize the location of the "log out..." menu item. Because that is always hidden.

Note that this is marked as a duplicate of [How do I fix fonts not rendering and missing letters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584922/how-do-i-fix-fonts-not-rendering-and-missing-letters) but the solution there is to upgrade to 15.04. I'm on 16.04, so should be past that.

Comment: After rebooting do fonts return to normal?

Comment: Yup. Reboot resolves the problem.

Comment: Maybe try <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F1> to open console and <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<F7> to go back to deskop? I've been on 16.04 for years and never experienced anything like this or remember it posted by others. You could also try Kernel 4.14.27 like I'm running: https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa but I don't think that will change much.

Comment: Something else to try before rebooting is to log out and back in again.

Comment: I'm trying the suggestions in that possible duplicate, but it's tricky to try that quickly because it doesn't happen every day.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've tried switching to another TTY and back. That hasn't done the trick, sadly.